# Set delay time for a loop execution

Tags: javascript, delay, settimeout

I'm trying to delay the execution of a loop by 3000ms, this is my code so far, but I keep on getting an error, does anyone can tell me why I'm getting error? Thanks in advance.

```
function contrEmpty(x,y,ev) {
  setTimeout(function () {for (var i=0; i<=4; i++) {
    if ((table[x+i+1][y] != 'R') && (table[x+i+1][y] != 'Y')) {
        table[x+i+1][y] = table[x+i][y];
        table[x+i][y] = 0;
        var ultPosX = x+i+1;  
        var ultPosY = y;
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        var dest=document.getElementById((x+i).toString()+y.toString()).childNodes;
        var dom=document.getElementById((x+i).toString()+y.toString());
        dom.removeChild(dest[0]);
        var newRR= document.getElementById((x+i+1).toString()+(y).toString()).appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));
    }
}
}, 3000);
var cell = ev;

}
```

Comment: Code seems to be valid from the first look... what errors are you getting

Comment: What do you mean you are getting an error? What error are you getting?

Comment: After 3000ms i get: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cloneNode' of null (anonymous function)

Comment: Simplified version of your code works as **expected**: http://jsfiddle.net/w2jgbah6/

Comment: document.getElementById(data) == null

Comment: @A.Blub can you please give me an example based on my script?

Comment: @Mikey keep on getting the error message...

Comment: @FabioEnne Ok, yeah I thought you might have a problem related to your delay or for loop, but that is not it when I see what your error message is.

Comment: Your error means, that no element wasnt found with the id data, which you want to clone

Comment: @A.Blub Yes, right... but if I took out the setTimeout function, everything works fine.. Cloning the node works fine, I get that error only when I use the setTimeout function...

Comment: In addition to what A.Blub said, `console.log(data)` to see what value it holds. Maybe you are not getting the expected value you expect.

Comment: @FabioEnne Weird, cloning works with the timeout http://jsfiddle.net/w2jgbah6/1/

Comment: @A.Blub No good, it seems to lost all the information inside the variables Dom,Data and Dest. I've got no idea on how to solve this.

Comment: @Mikey I lose my variables Data, Dom and Dest...

Comment: What do you mean: "I lose my variables"....You mean they are undefined? Anyway, do you console log them within the for loop to see what it returns.

Comment: @Mikey yes, sorry.. They are undefined...